# GLTFLoader error: Cannot read property 'itemStart' of undefined

Tags: three.js

For the sake of saving 12 megs I've got to switch from an OBJloader to GLTFLoader only I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemStart' of undefined

html

```
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>

...

  // Load the creature
  function load_creature()
  {
        // creature loader

        var images = [
            "./textures/00.jpg",
        ];


        var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( images[0] );

     // var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
     var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();


     // var creature = './obj/trex.obj'
     var creature = './gltf/trex.gltf'

    // Load a glTF resource
    loader.load(

        // resource URL
        './gltf/rex.gltf',

        // called when the resource is loaded
        function ( gltf ) {

            scene.add( gltf.scene );

            gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
            gltf.scene; // THREE.Scene
            gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Scene>
            gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
            gltf.asset; // Object

        },
        // called while loading is progressing
        function ( xhr ) {

            console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

        },
        // called when loading has errors
        function ( error ) {

            console.log( 'An error happened' );

        }
    );


    // Load creature
    var trex = load_creature();
```

I'm new to three.js and I can't see where I'm going wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you open the console in your project you can see the ThreeJS version in the very first line:

> THREE.WebGLRenderer 96

Make sure your GLTFLoader has the same version. So in my case it's 96.

[https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/**r96**/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js](https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r96/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js)

Make sure you modify the bold part of the URL to your ThreeJS Version to get the right code.

Thanks Mugen87 for providing the Informations I just wanted to wrap it up.

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure that your `three.js` library file and external example files like `GLTFLoader` are from the same release. We had the exact same issue some time ago in the `three.js` [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/gltfloader-itemstart-error/9502) and the root cause was a version mismatch of the used files.

`three.js R112`